# How do you download something using wget and the download URL when the web page requires a checkbox ticking?

Tags: unix, download, wget, url

I want to download some data. On the web page where the download is, there is a box that needs checking to confirm that the terms have been agreed before allowing this download. When I try to download on unix using wget and the download URL, I get a file with "Terms Of Download Checkbox Left Unchecked" rather than the file that I want. Is there any way of "checking the box" and agreeing to the terms when using wget so that I can download my data this way?

Comment: Usually not possible. An automated download without checking such box would mean you can download without agreeing to the terms, which they want to avoid, so they'll ensure that you need to check it manually. It is also a way to prevent auto download scripts to download and generate bandwidth usage.

Comment: If this is just a simple HTTP form, without any Javascript etc., it is possible. In short, you should use `curl` instead of `wget` and use a small script that: 1) gets the download page; 2) identifies the name of form field related to the checkbox and submits the form (it's just a matter of sending appropriate HTTP data, you should make yourself familiar with the structure of a POST request); 3) downloads the file (it can either happen automatically after step 2 or you have to follow redirect). If the form is static, ie. fields always have the same name, you can skip step 1.

Comment: I'd have a look at JDownloader for anything which requires hoop-jumping. it has many hoop-avoidance schemes for this type of thing - often you complete the requirements once & it will repeat the action invisibly after that.

Comment: Without more information about how this concrete website works, it is hard to give any advice at all. As @raj said, if no JS is involved you can probably send an HTTP POST to the form address, and with JS you could try to use Selenium to download the file. To get more help, please add a small example or a link to the webpage you are trying to use.